# Can screen reader read the expanded/collapsed state of an input element with role ‘combobox’?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I know with aria-expanded screen reader should be reading the expanded states. But does anyone know if it’s possible with `<input role=“combobox”>`?

I tried a couple of variations but the only one that read the expanded states is with role listbox.

Heres a simple stackblitz to show what I mean
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jxzyqr?file=index.html

Comment: What are your means of testing? What doesn’t work? Just to be clear: `listbox` should not have `aria-expanded` at all, so it’s weird that you mention this as the only case working. [`aria-expanded` always goes onto the toggle that opens the listbox](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/#wai-ariaroles,states,andproperties), in this case the `combobox`.

Answer (score 0):

The collapsed/expanded state of a combobox is read when you use the aria-expanded on an input with the combobox role.

- aria-expanded=false when the list of values is collapsed
- aria-expanded=true when the list of values is expanded

Visit the [ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/) to find examples of different types of comboboxes.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, screen readers can typically read the expanded/collapsed state of an input element with the role combobox when proper aria attributes , such as aria-expanded, are used in the web page or application.

Comment: Can you show me an example of this? I can’t seem to get it to read the states

Comment: This reads very much like an AI answer. Be aware that [AI answers are banned for now on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).